# Cisco ASA tags (again)

Tags: support, retag-request

I'm posting a new one, since the other one got marked as completed.

Please merge the following tags into [cisco-asa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-asa)

- [cisco-pix](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-pix)
- [pix](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pix)
- [asa5505](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asa5505)
- [asa-5510](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/asa-5510)

PIX and ASA are essentialy the same hardware, only that the ASA is newer and more powerful (and can run the latest software).

Comment: Is PIX > ASA totally legit though? Because a PIX box has "Cisco PIX" written on the front of it, not "Cisco ASA"

Comment: I admit, it's a gray zone.. Perhaps others can comment/discuss further on

Comment: Hopefully someone else will come along with an opinion ;) Otherwise if nobody has an opinion within a few days I'll make the merge. Honestly I don't think it's going to be an issue, becuase I don't think people really check their tags after creating their question.

Comment: I agree with John and Mark below - the PIX and ASA are separate product lines, with separate configuration syntax, capabilities, etc. They should stay separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that PIX != ASA, so should retain separate tags. ASA may supersede PIX but that doesn't make them equal. Seems to me it would be a bit like merging `windows-server-2003` with `windows-server-2008`.

Comment: Yeah, true. Lets leave them separated.

Answer (score 1):

These have been done except for [cisco-pix](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-pix) -> [cisco-asa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco-asa) because I think that one needs some public discussion before committing.